# Arduino interrupt button calls multiple ISRs

Tags: arduino, interrupt, isr

For a project I'm using an Arduino Mega2560 to control a couple of stepper motors with the AccelStepper library. It's the first time I'm using Arduino and I'm writing everything in Arduino IDE 2.0 (I also tried it with IDE 1.8 but no change). It's coming along quite nicely and it's a lot of fun! Everything seems to work as intended. Except for 1 thing.

I'm using 4 buttons to trigger certain events in my code, using the interrupt function. I'm doing this because the accelStepper library asks a lot of proccesing from the arduino and I need as many steps/sec as I can get. When 1 of the interrupts is activated it somehow calls another with it. I've removed everything from the code except the interrupt part to see if just the interrupts would work, but I still have the same issue. With this code I would expect to see a print in the serial of the button I pressed. However, when I press button one it sometimes prints both button 1 and button 2. When I press button 2 it always calls button 1 as well. Sometimes button 1 is printed first, sometimes button 2 is printed first. When I press button 3, button 2 is always called and when I press button 4, button 3 is always called.

As you can see in the code, I'm using port 18 through 21 as interrupt ports and their grounds are all connected to the same GND port on the Arduino. I tried disconnecting all the grounds and only connected button 1 with the Arduino GND. But somehow it still triggers button 2 as long as the cable of the button is still plugged into pin 19. Even though the ground of button 2 is not connected.

What am I doing wrong? Did I misunderstand how the interrupts with input_pullup works? Or am I doing something wrong in my code?

I'm running out of ideas so any help is appreciated!

```
// Define pins numbers
const int button1 = 18;
const int button2 = 19;
const int button3 = 20;
const int button4 = 21;

// Define variables
volatile bool button1Pressed = false;
volatile bool button2Pressed = false;
volatile bool button3Pressed = false;
volatile bool button4Pressed = false;
float timeTrigger1 = 0;
float timeTrigger2 = 0;
float timeTrigger3 = 0;
float timeTrigger4 = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Startup begins");

  pinMode(button1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button1), interrupt1, FALLING);

  pinMode(button2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button2), interrupt2, FALLING);

  pinMode(button3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button3), interrupt3, FALLING);

  pinMode(button4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button4), interrupt4, FALLING);

  Serial.println("Startup finished");
}

void loop() {
  if (button1Pressed) {
    Serial.println("button 1 was pressed");
    button1Pressed = false;
  }
  if (button2Pressed) {
    Serial.println("button 2 was pressed");
    button2Pressed = false;
  }
  if (button3Pressed) {
    Serial.println("button 3 was pressed");
    button3Pressed = false;
  }
  if (button4Pressed) {
    Serial.println("button 4 was pressed");
    button4Pressed = false;
  }
}


void interrupt1() {
  if (millis() - timeTrigger1 >= 500) {
    timeTrigger1 = millis();
    button1Pressed = true;
  }
}

void interrupt2() {
  if (millis() - timeTrigger2 >= 500) {
    timeTrigger2 = millis();
    button2Pressed = true;
  }
}

void interrupt3() {
  if (millis() - timeTrigger3 >= 500) {
    timeTrigger3 = millis();
    button3Pressed = true;
  }
}

void interrupt4() {
  if (millis() - timeTrigger4 >= 500) {
    timeTrigger4 = millis();
    button4Pressed = true;
  }
}
```

EDIT: checking the button state once the ISR is called did the trick. Like the code below.

```
void interrupt1() {
  if (millis() - timeTrigger1 >= 500 && digitalRead(button1)==LOW) {
    timeTrigger1 = millis();
    button1Pressed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doing floating-point math in your interrupt handlers strikes me as a horribly bad idea - and it's completely pointless, as all the values involved are integers.  But I think the problem is that the wires going to your buttons are acting as antennas - how long are these wires?  You may need stronger pull-up resistors (1K or so) than the weak built-in pull-ups.  You may need to re-read the button state in the ISR to verify that the button is actually being pressed, rather than a momentary burst of noise.

Comment: Looks like you need to debounce your buttons, either using HW or SW.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for your reply. I think you're right about the antennas. The wires are jumpercables of about 50cm. I tried adding resistors outside of the Arduino but it didn't work (might be of my limited electrical knowledge). Your idea about adding a piece of software to check if the button is actually pressed seem to do the trick. so thank you very much for that! I realise this doesnt solve the issue with the antennas but for now it will do, since it's only a test setup. ps. I used float because integer overflows too quickly. I changed it to unsighed long, since millis returns that

Comment: By the way, I notice getting downvotes. Had that problem before with a question as well. Is there anything in my question that might cause this? I would like to improve my questions where possible so in the future I have more chance on getting answers

Comment: Where did you add those resistors you're talking about? Does this happen with only one button wired? I don't think your setup should have such strong crosstalk to trigger the state.

Comment: You really should provide a circuit diagram showing how your buttons are wired to the GPIO port.